# how can you perform calculation in case statement of sql and display it as comment with other values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

table given is called LEAVE
LEAVE has 2 columns  Leavetype of type varchar type and allocated_days of number type.

leave:

leavetype             allocated_days
sick                   5
marriage               10
accident               20
maternity              90

Company updated its policies and now the changes are

leave:

```
leavetype             allocated_days
     sick                   add  5 days
     marriage               add  5 days
     accident               substract 5 days
     maternity              multiply with 2
```

with the help of case in sql produce this output

leave:

```
leavetype             allocated_days    revised policy
     sick                   5              10
     marriage               10             15
     accident               20             15
     maternity              90             180
```

the code I tried was:

```
select leavetype,allocated_days
 case 
    when leavetype='sick' then  (allocated_days+5)
    when leavetype='marriage' then (allocated_days+5)
    when leavetype='accident' then (allocated_days-5)
    when leavetype='maternity' then (allocatef_days*2)
 else allocated_days
end "revised policy" from leave;
```

error says:

> from keyword not properly placed

I am a learning aspirant and I could not find any related source to refer and learn from please help

Comment: You are missing a comma before the `case`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing comma, but also you can simplify your query a little bit :

```
select leavetype,allocated_days,
 case 
    when leavetype in ('sick','marriage') then (allocated_days+5)    
    when leavetype='accident' then (allocated_days-5)
    when leavetype='maternity' then (allocated_days*2)
 else allocated_days
end "revised policy" from leave;
```